# How to change current URL and open new tab on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, stringify

I need this to replace every link on a page that has a current URL with something like:

```
    ("body a").on("click", function() {
     window.open("new_page.html?test=1&test=2", "_newtab");
     window.location.replace('replace_current_page.html?test=1&test=2');
     });
```

I'm not sure that window.open is the right function. Maybe replacing the href is a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be every link, Do they need to go to the same page? I'm not exactly sure what you need to do but you could do something like this as well.

```
/* allows you to open link in new window */
$(function() {
     $('a').each(function() {
         $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
         /* uncomment if you need to change the href here
         $(this).attr('href', "mylink.htm"); */
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, they all have to change to the same link and open to a new link. Same function for all links.

Answer (score 0):

function clicked(ressource){

```
            var link = $(ressource);
            alert('the current url of the link is ' + link.attr('href'));

            $('a').each(function(){
                var link = $(this);

                if(link.attr('href') == window.location){
                    link.attr('href', 'new-external-link.html' 
                    "open in new window" );
                    and 
                   current-page.html and goes-to-new-link.html


                    link.text(link.attr('href'));
                }
            });
           return false; 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://1a-android.de">1a-android.de</a><br>
    <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/">link1</a><br>
    <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/">link2</a><br>
    <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://1a-android.de">link3</a><br>
    <span id="location">The location of this page is: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wzpe5vs9/1/) goes in the right direction for you. If not please specify your question better.

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rankseller.com/responsive/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js?v=0.04"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function clicked(ressource){

                var link = $(ressource);
                alert('the current url of the link is ' + link.attr('href'));

                $('a').each(function(){
                    var link = $(this);

                    if(link.attr('href') == window.location){
                        link.attr('href', '#my-replacement');
                        link.text(link.attr('href'));
                    }
                });
               return false; 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://1a-android.de">1a-android.de</a><br>
        <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/">link1</a><br>
        <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/">link2</a><br>
        <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://1a-android.de">link3</a><br>
        <span id="location">The location of this page is: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

```
  <html> 
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rankseller.com/responsive/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js?v=0.04"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function clicked(ressource){
                    var link = $(ressource);
                    var href = link.attr('href');
                    link.attr('href', 'http://1a-android.de');
                    link.attr('target', '_blank');

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location = href;
                    }, 2000);

                    return true; 
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://1a-android.de">1a-android.de</a><br>
            <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://partners.webmasterplan.com/click.asp?ref=607071&site=6460&type=b361&bnb=361">link1</a><br>
            <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/">link2</a><br>
            <a onclick="return clicked(this);" href="http://guter-webhoster.de">link3</a><br>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Who voted my support for this question down, for what reason?

Comment: what I am trying to do is replace the current url with a new one and when the new link loads in a new window .. the current page goes to another page ...

Comment: specify: "replace the current url with a new one"....
You could use from my code above the var link = $(this); to get the url of the link.

window.open(link.attr('href'), "_newtab");

Maybe you must add the www.youdomain.com/ as a prefix.

Comment: so for example if the current link on the page is      <a href="google.com">Link 1</a>   The new link specified will overwrite it ... I am testing your code